# Is there an OSS license that works for this:

Tags: open-source

Say you started as SaaS service with freemium business model such 37Signals - Basecamp or Dropbox etc..

Is there an OSS license that says that you can use the source code etc.. but you cant release a SaaS based on it, esssentially released in good faith with non-compete expectations. e.g. if 37Signals released the source for highrise, basecamp etc.. someone could start 37signals4lesss.com (albeit once they built the same bit of provisioning logic) and damage the core business model.

Comment: Your domain name is backwards.

Answer (score 6):

No.

The [OSS definition](http://opensource.org/docs/osd) (point 6) disallows usage restrictions:

> ### No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor
>
> The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're looking for an open source license, since you want to restrict how people use your software even once they have a copy. A Visible Source license might work, an example is the [Zope Visible Source License](http://www.zope.com/about_us/legal/zvsl.html).